# Why does Speedx not launch from dash or terminal?

Tags: 22.04, software-center, snap, gnome-dash

Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.  Ubuntu Software says that it is installed, but Synaptic Pkg Mgr detects nothing in searching for "speedx".
When I click on the Speedx icon in dash, nothing happens.  When I use terminal, I get
$ speedx
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "wayland-egl"
in "".
Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.
Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Aborted (core dumped)

I reinstalled the application with no success.  I searched the internet for the above "failure" and tried the suggested fixes to no avail.  Bug?

Answer (score 1):

The application you installed is a snap, and there's some troubleshooting tips on the snap store page for the application, here: https://snapcraft.io/speedx

The reason you don't see it in Synaptic is because that application only manages deb based packages, not snaps.

Comment: Thanks.  No success with tips, so posted a bug report at snapcraft link.